# JSX props should not use arrow functions eslint warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two component that one passes some func as prop to another and I am not sure what is the proper way to do this without having to receive an eslint error:

Code:

```
<Parent>
  const doSmthHandler = useCallback((id: number)=> {
   //do some stuff 
  },[])
  <ComponentB>
     doSmth={()=>doSmthHandler(id)} // Here I get eslint warning: JSX props should not use arrow functions eslint warning
  </ComponentB>
</Parent>
```

Component B receives `doSmth` prop as function and has a button such as:

```
<Button onPress={doSmth}>Do stuff</Button>
```

I wonder how do I pass some argument into the cuntion passed as cb prop into another component that I dont get eslint errors!

Comment: Have you tried the React hook `useCallback`? You can find documentation for it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: I actually have it already under callBack() but the warning still shows!

Comment: dont see any example from above link how do you pass arg to the func without having to use inline arrow fn

Comment: @isnihalsi the problem is that you're passing a callback directly as a property. You should declare it before passing it down to the component to avoid the ESLint warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're passing a callback as a property directly. You could declare it as a wrapper using `useCallback` before passing it down to the component, like so:

```
const doSmthHandlerWrapper = useCallback(
    () => doSmthHandler(id),
    [id]
)

<ComponentB>
    doSmth={doSmthHandlerWrapper}
</ComponentB>
```

Comment: how do you pass `id` inside doSmthHandlerWrapper?

Comment: Have you declared `id` on your component (`Parent` in your example code)? If so, it should be visible to the function via closure when the it's called.

Comment: no, actually this is the key point here, I would like to pass an arg to doSmthHandlerWrapper() for ex doSmthHandlerWrapper(1)

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with a broader version of your code, showing what you're tring to do?

Comment: it seems like I can simply do like <ComponentB
     doSmth={doSmthHandler(id)}/>

Comment: you can, but this function will be called as soon as the component is rendered, therefore its return value will be passed as `doSmith`, not the function itself.

Comment: yeah so thats why also we wrap fn into useCallback fn so it doesnt createthe function everytime for each render!

Comment: but this makes an issue to me if the function will be called as soon as the component render, I dont want to be called on render but I would want it to be called when needed, like other cmp triggers!

Comment: that is why I was asking for a code snippet. If I could take a look at what you're tring to do, I could provide a more precise answer.